# Javascript/jQuery listener not working with Underscore.js templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, jquery-events, underscore.js-templating

I'm building a webapp using underscore.js to create the templates. The thing is, when I render a simple template like this:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="person-template">
    <% person.forEach(function(p) { %>
        <a class="username"> <%= p.username %> </a>
    <% }); %>
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var template = document.getElementById('person-template');
    var renderTemplate = _.template(template.innerHTML);

    container.innerHTML = renderTemplate({
        person: /* ajax object callback response ... */
    });
</script>
```

If I try to use the person's id to do something with my Javascript. The function isn't working and there is no error on the console. Example:

```
$('.username').click( function() {
    console.log('hello!');
});
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't work:

- `$(document).ready( function...`
- `$(container).find('.username').on('click', function...`
- It works with a `window.setTimeout(funciton(){...},1500)` but I want a better way to do it.

By the way, this is a very simple example, just to explain the problem.

Comment: The template renders perfect. The problem is that I can't interact with it after the render. Why is important the type of loop here? @jisaak

Comment: have you tried passing the rendered html into a `$(  )`  and then applying the event listeners? so `$(container).find('#person').on('click',...`

Comment: In your case all the anchor tags have the same id may be it is because of that.

Comment: Also tried right now, but it doesn't work. I'll update the question with this case. @JohnProestakes

Comment: @Neelesh it is just a simple example, the real app is different. I'll change it in the question.

Comment: When you say "isn't working", what exactly do you mean? Are you not seeing the `<a>` tags corresponding to the persons, or is clicking on them without effect? I have a strong suspicion that this is due to your ajax response arriving only after you've already rendered the template, since it does work if you add the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.username', function(e) {
    console.log('hello!');
});
```

This will work for all elements with 'username' class in the body, whether already present or dynamically added later.

Comment: This known as delegating events. It's a good advice, though not a complete answer.